# Don't add new ethernet interfaces, use it as eth0

Tags: debian, networking, udev, ethernet

I have multiple ARM devices on which Debian runs. I have a single image saved from the SD Card and intend to use it on all devices.

Now I have the problem that, each time the MAC address of the eth, wlan, etc... port changes, it adds a new entry to the `70-persistent-net.rules` file. For me this is a problem because in my `/etc/network/interfaces` file I only have `eth0` set up. If the interface then gets linked to `eth1`, it won't connect to the network. Since no screen is connected it is a hassle to redo this process every time.

Is there a way to tell the OS to always use `eth0` when the MAC address of the ethernet interface changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I put in my `70-persistent-net.rules` file; you might only need the first two:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="*", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth0", NAME="eth0"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="*", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth1", NAME="eth1"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="*", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth2", NAME="eth2"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="*", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth3", NAME="eth3"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="*", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth4", NAME="eth4"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="*", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth5", NAME="eth5"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="*", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth6", NAME="eth6"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="*", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth7", NAME="eth7"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="*", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth8", NAME="eth8"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="*", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth9", NAME="eth9"
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Delete your current interface name prescriptions:

   ```
   # rm /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
   ```
2. Make sure they don't get regenerated:

   ```
   # touch /etc/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules
   ```
3. That's it.

Comment: I've been softlinking 70-persistent-net.rules to /dev/null as a hack.  Will a null generator stanza work the same and ensure the 70-rules file stays blank?  That's excellent, if so.

Comment: Symlinking to `/dev/null` is probably clearer than creating an empty file, though both should work. If you deactivate the generator by either means, nothing will create or modify `70-persistent-net.rules` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of /etc/rc.local

```
 if ifconfig | grep -q eth0 
 then
   : > /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
   reboot
 fi
```

This sould do the job, and in case you reboot on same devices, you reboot only once.

As a faster alternatives, you can delete `70-persistent-net.rules` on shutdown, this suppose you only do scheduled shutdown.

Comment: So using wildcards like `*` in the MAC adress field in the `70-persistent-net.rules` file is not allowed?